# IIS Administration using PowerShell 2 and Modules on Windows 2008 R1

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, powershell

I have a PowerShell 2 script to automatically register managed modules with IIS7.  With PowerShell 2 I used `import-module webadministration` rather than the snap-in.

Is it possible to install the IIS7 web administration module (rather than the snap-in) on Window Server 2008 R1 when PowerShell 2 is installed?  If so, how?

This would have the benefit of simplifying my script, otherwise, I will need to attempt to target two different server platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to load the IIS provider as the same thing on both 2008 and 2008R2. On 2008 the IIS provider is provided as only a snapin, and on 2008R2 it is provided as only a module.

With a little bit of coding, you can actually determine which to use, and dynamically load the module or snapin in your script, depending on which is necessary. I took this code from http://forums.iis.net/t/1166784.aspx when I was having a similar problem.

```
$ModuleName = "WebAdministration"
$ModuleLoaded = $false
$LoadAsSnapin = $false

if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 2) {
    if ((Get-Module -ListAvailable | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}) -contains $ModuleName) {
        Import-Module $ModuleName
        if ((Get-Module | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}) -contains $ModuleName) {
            $ModuleLoaded = $true
        } else {
            $LoadAsSnapin = $true
        }
    } elseif ((Get-Module | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}) -contains $ModuleName) {
        $ModuleLoaded = $true
    } else {
        $LoadAsSnapin = $true
    }
} else {
    $LoadAsSnapin = $true
}

if ($LoadAsSnapin) {
    if ((Get-PSSnapin -Registered | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}) -contains $ModuleName) {
        Add-PSSnapin $ModuleName
        if ((Get-PSSnapin | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}) -contains $ModuleName) {
            $ModuleLoaded = $true
        }
    } elseif ((Get-PSSnapin | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}) -contains $ModuleName) {
        $ModuleLoaded = $true
    }
}
```

Before attempting to do anything with the IIS provider, check to ensure that `$ModuleLoaded` is true, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I wound up taking a similar approach, however, this version is much more robust than what I came up with.  Thanks!!