# PowerShell Snap-In for IIS 7.0 IIsProviderSnapIn vs WebAdministration

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, powershell

I am attempting to install the [Windows PowerShell Snap-In for IIS 7.0](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/powershell) on a server running server 2008 with service pack 2 installed, so I can use the `WebAdministration` snappin.

On Installation I'm faced with an error

> Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product.

Neither Get-PSSnapin nor Get-Module -ListAvailable show `WebAdministration`, but I do have `IIsProviderSnapIn` listed. Also, The script provided as an answer to [IIS Administration using PowerShell 2 and Modules on Windows 2008 R1](https://serverfault.com/questions/201787/iis-administration-using-powershell-2-and-modules-on-windows-2008-r1) returns False.

Is this an old version of `WebAdministration` ?

Is this listed under Programs and Features as "Microsoft Windows PowerShell provider for IIS 7.0" ? and if so, can I safely uninstall it, and install the PowerShell Snap-in from the original link?

(Or alternatively, can I use IIsProviderSnapIn to get a list for all the currently running sites, as I would do with the `Get-Website` in `WebAdministration` module?)

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I'm still not sure exactly what the `IIsProviderSnapIn` snap-in is compared to `WebAdministration`, I've ended up with a modified version of an answer to 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924217/powershell-load-webadministration-in-ps1-script-on-both-iis-7-and-iis-7-5
which loads in the `WebAdministration` snap-in or module if available, otherwise uses the `IIsProviderSnapIn`.

```
$iisVersion = Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\software\microsoft\InetStp"
$useIISProviderSnappin = $False

if ($iisVersion.MajorVersion -eq 7)
{
    if ($iisVersion.MinorVersion -ge 5)
    {
        Import-Module WebAdministration
    }           
    else
    {

        if(Get-PSSnapIn -Registered | Where {$_.Name -eq "WebAdministration"}) 
        {
            if (-not (Get-PSSnapIn | Where {$_.Name -eq "WebAdministration"})) 
            {
                Add-PSSnapIn WebAdministration
            }
        }
        elseif(Get-PSSnapIn -Registered | Where {$_.Name -eq "IIsProviderSnapIn"})
        {
            #older versions of server 2008 don't have the webadministration module!
            if (-not (Get-PSSnapIn | Where {$_.Name -eq "IIsProviderSnapIn"})) 
            {
                Add-PSSnapIn IIsProviderSnapIn
            }

            $useIISProviderSnappin = $True
        }
        else 
        {
            throw "Unable to import any suitable modules... :( "
        }
    }
}

Function Get-IISWebsite()
{
    if($useIISProviderSnappin)
    {
        return dir iis:\sites
    }
    else
    {
        return Get-Website
    }
}
```